# Hide specific content from an iterative loop and show in hidden panel

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I have this component here and i want that whenever i click on the div content showing the hidden div gets triggered and show the hidden form. I have done that but now i also need to hide the div of that content that was showing when i trigger the hidden div and show that hidden div in place of that particular div but not under all divs. All other content should just remain as it is. Can any one help me? Here is my component
[Example Component](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-list-oqpkbw)

Answer (score 0):

An edit is made to the example component.
Find the link posted below
https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-list-lj18vu?file=src/app/app.component.ts

You need to add a flag to each and every item, on click of an item you need to make all the items flag as false and that particular item flag as true

Then it works as expected.

Happy Coding :)

Comment: No i don't think i need to add flags here. Since i just need to edit the content. The content is dynamic so user can add maybe upto 10 contents containing heading and paragaphs and pictures. So i want that whenever i click on first paragraph then the hidden panel will open only under it and not under all and also that content will be shwoing in textboxes so that i can edit it and send it to API. As for the hiding the previously content i also need answer